# How to send logs from tomcat docker container to catalina.out?

Tags: tomcat, logging, docker

I'm using docker container based on docker image `tomcat:7-jre8`. Tomcat is running in foreground and catalina logs are sent to `stdout`. 
The file `catalina.out` doesn't contain any logs. I would like to redirect a logs from `stdout` to the file `catalina.out`, because I want to store a logs outside of docker container. I'm using mounted volume on a host machine.

Tomcat is launched using following command from `Dockerfile`:

```
CMD ["bin/catalina.sh", "run"]
```

Can you give me any hints how to redirect logs to file?

I tried to run tomcat with `bin/startup.sh` script, but it's not working. Is the service right way?

Answer (score 6):

Within the docker worlds, logging to stdout its considered as a best practice.

Don't try to work against it, instead try capturing the logs by calling `docker logs [containername]`.

Then use a [logging-driver](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/overview/) to send to logs to a specific file.